# Use of htaccess with rewrite rule for multilanguage site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I come up to the following `.htaccess` file for my multil. project.
However there are some problems I'm not able to solve.

The target is to rewrite URLs e.g. from:

```
/en/prod/index.php
```

to

```
/prod/index.php?lang=en
```

This has to work for every folders, not only for prod.
Sometimes the links have already some variable after the `?` so rewrite rule should detect this `?` and change it to `&`.
With my code I'm able to substitute the `?` with an `&`, but this applies also if no `?` is present!

Second (**and MAIN**) problem:
If the file exists (in my previous example) `/prod/index.php` then the browser should display this page, but if the file doesn't exist the all requests should be redirected to `index.php`.

With my code the requests are **ALWAYS** redirected because the file doesn't correspond to the link so the condition doesn't match.

Thank you for any help!

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(\??)(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(it|en)/(.*)$ [NC]

#is it possible here to have %3 instead of rewriting (it|en)? Does not work...
RewriteRule ^(it|en)/(.*)$ /%3/$2?lang=%3&%2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(it|en)/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%2 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%2 -d
RewriteRule ^(it|en)/(.*)$ /$2?lang=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(it|en)/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%2 !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%2 !-d
RewriteRule ^(it|en)/(.*)$ /index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain me better the `%2` after `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}`? The first part of `RewriteRule` cannot contain a variable like `%1` or `$1` to avoid repeating the `(it|en)`?

Comment: @Perocat That attempts to determine whether the matched group `(.*)` in the `%{REQUEST_URI}` line exists or not.

Comment: Thank you! So it check if `DOCUMENT_ROOT/it/files/file.php` -> which becomes `DOCUMENT_ROOT/files/file.php` exists (where `$2` is `files/file.php` taken from the `(.*)` after `/(it|en)/` in the first RewriteCond)?

Comment: @Perocat correct, in order to backreference matches in rewrite conditions, you need to use %1, %2, %3, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these generic rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2 -d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.+)$ /$2?lang=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you! What about the variable after the file which should be added after `lang=$1`?

Comment: That will be taken care of by using `QSA` flag. Which will make a URI like this `/prod/index.php?lang=fr&foo=bar&id=123`

Comment: And the original `?` when language was not present will be automatically replaces by `&`?

Comment: Yes that is true, `QSA` flag does that for us.